# ionic framework can't load local notifications

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am taking Coursera's course for Multiplatform Mobile Devices and it says to call:

```
ionic plugin add de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Toms-MBP:confusioncordova toddcoulson$ ionic platform add android
>   Error: Platform android already added.
>
> Toms-MBP:confusioncordova toddcoulson$ ionic plugin add
>   de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification Installing
>   "de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" for android
>
> Installing "cordova-plugin-device" for android
>
> Using this version of Cordova with older version of cordova-android
>   is being deprecated. Consider upgrading to cordova-android@5.0.0 or
>   newer.
>
> Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-device':CordovaError: The provided
>   path
>   "/Users/toddcoulson/documents/coursera/fullstack/confusioncordova/platforms/android"
>   is not an Android project.
>       at new android_parser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/metadata/android_parser.js:35:15)
>       at new PlatformApiPoly (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/platforms/PlatformApiPoly.js:62:20)
>       at Object.getPlatformApi (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/platforms/platforms.js:70:23)
>       at handleInstall (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:610:29)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:407:28
>       at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:509:49
>       at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
>
> Failed to install
>   'de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification':CordovaError: The
>   provided path
>   "/Users/toddcoulson/documents/coursera/fullstack/confusioncordova/platforms/android"
>   is not an Android project.
>       at new android_parser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/metadata/android_parser.js:35:15)
>       at new PlatformApiPoly (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/platforms/PlatformApiPoly.js:62:20)
>       at Object.getPlatformApi (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/platforms/platforms.js:70:23)
>       at handleInstall (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:610:29)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:407:28
>       at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
>       at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:509:49
>       at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
>
> Error: The provided path
>   "/Users/toddcoulson/documents/coursera/fullstack/confusioncordova/platforms/android"
>   is not an Android project.

EDIT: I do think this is an issue getting the emulator for android to work. I thought I had things setup, but I never got the emulator working for android. Here is the error when running emulator:
Total time: 2.031 secs

> Built the following apk(s): 
>     /Users/toddcoulson/documents/coursera/fullstack/confusioncordova/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
>
> ANDROID_HOME=/Users/toddcoulson/Library/Android/sdk
>
> JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home
>
> No emulator specified, defaulting to testOne
>
> Waiting for emulator to start...
>
> emulator: Requested console port 5584: Inferring adb port 5585.
>   Creating filesystem with parameters:
>       Size: 69206016
>       Block size: 4096
>       Blocks per group: 32768
>       Inodes per group: 4224
>       Inode size: 256
>       Journal blocks: 1024
>       Label: 
>       Blocks: 16896
>       Block groups: 1
>       Reserved block group size: 7 Created filesystem with 11/4224 inodes and 1302/16896 blocks emulator: WARNING: Camera name 'webcam0'
>   is not found in the list of connected cameras. Use '-webcam-list'
>   emulator option to obtain the list of connected camera names.
>
> Hax is enabled Hax ram_size 0x77300000 HAX is working and emulator
>   runs in fast virt mode.
>
> emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5584 emulator:
>   Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5584
>
> [123145554325504]:WARNING:./android/base/files/IniFile.cpp:158:Failed
>   to process .ini file
>   /Users/toddcoulson/.android/emu-update-last-check.ini for reading.
>
> Unknown hax vcpu return 1

Another EDIT:
I was able to get the plug-in to load once I had the android project setup with ionic and got Android Studio to load in an emulator. The emulator is still giving an error I put in the comments, but it did allow me to get past these errors.

Comment: Did this course help you setup the Android environment? If not, there may be a problem there or you can simply try to re-add the platform again to see if that helps. You can do that by first doing `ionic platform remove android` and then `ionic platform add android`.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, removing the platform didn't fix anything. It seems like there may be something wrong with the path. Because it says android platform is added, but then it says provided path is not an android project. The course did help setup, but mostly it pointed to the docs online. It was helpful, and worked on Mac, but I am not sure my Android is setup right, clearly.

Comment: I forgot to mention, when I call remove android it gives me a lot of grandle paths missing:
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): /Users/toddcoulson/documents/coursera/fullstack/confusioncordova/platforms/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar

Comment: @Dexter - please see my edit above, I did go back and follow more of the installation instructions, but I cannot get the emulator to run. I tried to choose all of the latest items for emulating, but i am not really sure what to pick.

Comment: I tried to choose all of the latest items for emulating, but i am not really sure what to pick. I tried android TV, nexus 10, nexus 9, tried different cpus, tried different skins, nothing works.